# Can I separate email id in spreadsheet based on domain in columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have a list of 20000 email id which have emails from domains like gmail, ymail, gmx, hotmail, custom domains etc I have those list in a spreadsheet Column A. Can you help me separate them according to their domain in different columns?

For example gmail ids in column B and ymail in column C and so on....

Comment: Why tag this email? This is a "I have $any_sort_of_text" and I want to sort them based  on $criterium. The email part is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Putting them in different columns isn't really sorting them is it? It's more like separating them.

Comment: sorry.. i got automatic suggestion and so i chosen it... I am completely new here and have no idea how this world works...

Comment: yes...  but this is slightly different... in this i can get domain gmail.com, gmail.co.uk, separately... not intend to create duplicates... But yours also helped me to find the number of emails from different domains...

Comment: pardon? i couldnt understand what you say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your email address was in cell `A4` the following will extract the domain:

```
=MID(A4,FIND("@",A4)+1,99999)
```

This takes the MIDdle of a string, starting from the character were the @ was found, plus 1, followed by the next 99999 characters.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But what i was expecting is to separate full email address based on domain name separate columns...

Comment: For example 
adb@gmail.com, asd@gmail.com, adj@gmail.com, ghaj@ymail.com in columnA
It should be adb@gmail.com, asd@gmail.com, adj@gmail.com in column B and  ghaj@ymail.com in column C

Comment: What is the goal here?  Once you have the domains separated you can just sort the spreadsheet to get them grouped, or use filters, or pivot tables.  Putting similar data types into different columns rarely helps with a spreadsheet.